# how to expand a component on click to full screen width and height with animation in reactnative

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I have tried to implement the component expand to full screen in react native by using Layout animation in react-native but it was not good to look. Can any one help me in getting it?

```
changeLayout = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
};
```

I expect to expand the component on click to full screen and again collapse it on click.

Comment: LayoutAnimation works just fine out of the box to me. Can you show me how you are styling your component's dimensions? And, are you using android or iOS to test it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the initial value you want through the `animation`, obtain the screen `width` and `height`, and create a `click function` to execute.

This is an `example` that I made. Click [this link](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/change-view-use-animate-example-) if you want to run it yourself.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Text, View,Dimensions,Button } from 'react-native';

const screenwidth = Dimensions.get('screen').width
const screenheight = Dimensions.get('screen').height
class FadeInView extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(50),  
    fadeAnim2: new Animated.Value(50),
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }

  animatebutton() {
      Animated.timing(                  // Animate over time
      this.state.fadeAnim,            // The animated value to drive
      {
        toValue: screenheight,                
        duration: 10000,              // Make it take a while
      }
    ).start();     
        Animated.timing(                  // Animate over time
      this.state.fadeAnim2,            // The animated value to drive
      {
        toValue: screenwidth,                  
        duration: 10000,              // Make it take a while
      }
    ).start();                        // Starts the animation
  }

  render() {
    let { fadeAnim,fadeAnim2 } = this.state;

    return (
      <Animated.View                 // Special animatable View
        style={{
          ...this.props.style,
          height: fadeAnim, 
          width : fadeAnim2     
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

// You can then use your `FadeInView` in place of a `View` in your components:
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
    }
  }
  animatebutton(){
    this.fade.animatebutton();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} >
        <FadeInView style={{backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} ref={ani => this.fade = ani}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 28, textAlign: 'center', margin: 10}}>Fading in</Text>
        </FadeInView>
        <Button title="go animate" onPress={() => this.animatebutton()}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

OR

You can use `LayoutAnimation` that you want to use. [Look at my example.](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/layoutanimation-example?session_id=snack-session-y4eB29bZK)

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  LayoutAnimation,
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      check: false,
    }
  }

  onPresscheck() {

    // Uncomment to animate the next state change.
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);

    // Or use a Custom Layout Animation
    // LayoutAnimation.configureNext(CustomLayoutAnimation);

    this.setState({ check : !this.state.check});
  }

  render() {

    var middleStyle = this.state.check === false ? {width: 20,height:20} : {width: "100%",height:"100%"};

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.onPresscheck()}>
        <Text>pressbutton</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={[middleStyle, {backgroundColor: 'seagreen'}]}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  button: {
    width:"100%",
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin: 8,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: The LayoutAnimation is the easiest and the fastest to implement if you dont know what you are doing, like me.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this blog :

https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-animatable/

Also, try using this [library](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable). Use any animation type you want and render them.

Happy coding :)